# KieRespository instance giving null pointer exception when Jar running in Docker Environment

Tags: java, docker, drools, kie

When running our Java Spring Boot app (Fat Jar) on Docker Environment we are getting below error:

```
Error: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.builder.KieModule]: Factory method 'kieModule' threw an exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Method in our Drools Config class:

```
@Bean(KieModule)
public KieModule kieModule() {
   KieServices kservice = KieServices.Factory.get();
   final KieRepository kr = kservice.getRepository(); //failing here
   KieModule kieModule = new KieModule() {
        public ReleaseId getReleaseId(){ return releaseId.getDefaultReleaseId();}
};

kieRepository.addKieModule(kieModule);
return kieModule;

}
   
}
```

build.gradle has following dependencies

```
implementation 'org.kie:kie-spring:7.30.0:Final'
implementation 'org.drools:drools-core:7.30.0:Final'
implementation 'org.drools:drools-compiler:7.30.0:Final'
```

The functionality works fine in JVM and other servers but when deployed in internal Docker container it breaks at KieRepository instance and gives null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Solved by appending the kie.conf files using shadow plugin in gradle.

Add following in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies{classpath("com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:4.0.4")}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnengleman.shadow'

shadowJar{
 manifest{
    attribute('Main-Class': 'com.demo.HelloWorldApp')
}
append('META-INF/kie.conf')
}
```

Read more at [here](https://thewebspark.com/2022/01/30/error-kie-container-or-kiemodule-bean-null-pointer-exception-solved/)